# How to read file in ideone in java

Tags: java

I want to open, read, and edit file from my desktop. I am using Ideone online compiler. How do I read the file? I tried the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
class demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        File file = new File("C:/Users/psanghavi/Desktop/admin_confirmation_original.txt");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) 
        {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            char current;
            while (fis.available() > 0) 
            {
                current = (char) fis.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My desktop has file named: admin_confirmation_original.txt

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an exception? Wrong results read?

Comment: you can't read local files.host it anywhere and read from url

Comment: host it anywhere means? How?

Comment: @user2609410 website can't access your file system .and has lot of restriction .so if you want to solve this problem download jdk

Answer (score 2):

Currently, **No**. 
About the limit, Idebone FAQ say about this:

```
Can I write or read files in my program? - No
Can I access the network from my program? - No
```

You can learn more about many Ideone restricted rule at FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Ideoone doesn't support reading local files.

This is not an answer to your question, but wrt to the comments
if you want to read files hosted, you could access them using [URL class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
      try {
            final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in/robots.txt");
            //URL url = new URL("http://74.125.236.52/robots.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while (in.readLine() != null) {
                str = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have not tried it on file hosting sites.There are a lot of free file hostings available just google it.